# How to do chained coroutines in C++ 20

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

I am trying to chained coroutines. Foo2 will actually go async. Once Foo2 resume, the code should execute in the order of "resume Foo2" and "resume Foo1" (like 2 continuation). I am not clear on some details. First, when co_await b suspends, does it return a promise object immediately to the caller? Then co_await Foo2() happens. At this point I need to suspend but don't want to fire off thread t(run). Somewhere I think I need to wrap the promise/awaiter from Foo2() before co_await on it in Foo1().

```
void run(std::coroutine_handle<> h)
{
  std::cout<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<" "<<"in Run\n";
  std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(5));
  h.resume();
}

template<typename T>
struct task{

  struct promise_type {
    T val_;
    task get_return_object() { return {.h_ = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this)}; }
    std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
    std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
    void return_value(T val) { val_ = val; }
    void unhandled_exception() {}
  };

  bool await_ready() { return false; }
  void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h)
  {
    std::thread t(run, h);
    t.detach();
  }

  void await_resume() { }

  std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> h_;
};

template<typename T>
task<T> Foo2()
{ 
  std::cout<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<" "<<"in Foo2\n";
  task<T> b;
  co_await b;
  std::cout<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<" resume Foo2\n";
}

template<typename T>
task<T> Foo1()
{
  std::cout<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<" "<<"in Foo1\n";
  co_await Foo2<T>();
  std::cout<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<" resume Foo1\n";
}

int main()
{
  Foo1<int>();
  std::cout<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<" ""main end\n";  
  std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(30));
}
```

Comment: Promise objects are returned when the coroutine is first called, before any awaiting.

Comment: Your `task` class is really just a thread-switching awaiter that has an unrelated `promise_type` embedded in it. (Notice that `await_resume()` doesn't use the promise at all.)

Answer (score 10):

> does it return a promise object immediately

Promise objects are never returned. Promise object is created and stored inside the coroutine frame. It is destroyed together with coroutine frame.

What is returned to caller is "return object" of coroutine. It is created from object that is returned from `promise::get_return_object()` function when the coroutine first suspends (or is done). (`promise::get_return_object()` is called before the body of the coroutine starts its execution)

> At this point I need to suspend...

In order to await completion of another coroutine current coroutine needs to be suspended and stored somewhere to be resumed after awaited coroutine completes.

It can be stored outside in some context that is responsible for spinning coroutines (something like `io_service`) or inside awaited coroutine.

Here is an example of asynchronous (and single-threaded) `task<T>` coroutine that is awaitable.

It stores suspended coroutine inside coroutine promise of awaited coroutine and resumes it after coroutine value is computed.

```
#include <coroutine>
#include <optional>

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <chrono>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

// basic coroutine single-threaded async task example

template<typename T>
struct task_promise_type;

// simple single-threaded timer for coroutines
void submit_timer_task(std::coroutine_handle<> handle, std::chrono::seconds timeout);

template<typename T>
struct task;

template<typename T>
struct task_promise_type
{
    // value to be computed
    // when task is not completed (coroutine didn't co_return anything yet) value is empty
    std::optional<T> value;

    // corouine that awaiting this coroutine value
    // we need to store it in order to resume it later when value of this coroutine will be computed
    std::coroutine_handle<> awaiting_coroutine;

    // task is async result of our coroutine
    // it is created before execution of the coroutine body
    // it can be either co_awaited inside another coroutine
    // or used via special interface for extracting values (is_ready and get)
    task<T> get_return_object();

    // there are two kinds of coroutines:
    // 1. eager - that start its execution immediately
    // 2. lazy - that start its execution only after 'co_await'ing on them
    // here I used eager coroutine task
    // eager: do not suspend before running coroutine body
    std::suspend_never initial_suspend()
    {
        return {};
    }

    // store value to be returned to awaiting coroutine or accessed through 'get' function
    void return_value(T val)
    {
        value = std::move(val);
    }

    void unhandled_exception()
    {
        // alternatively we can store current exeption in std::exception_ptr to rethrow it later
        std::terminate();
    }

    // when final suspend is executed 'value' is already set
    // we need to suspend this coroutine in order to use value in other coroutine or through 'get' function
    // otherwise promise object would be destroyed (together with stored value) and one couldn't access task result
    // value
    auto final_suspend() noexcept
    {
        // if there is a coroutine that is awaiting on this coroutine resume it
        struct transfer_awaitable
        {
            std::coroutine_handle<> awaiting_coroutine;

            // always stop at final suspend
            bool await_ready() noexcept
            {
                return false;
            }
            std::coroutine_handle<> await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<task_promise_type> h) noexcept
            {
                // resume awaiting coroutine or if there is no coroutine to resume return special coroutine that do
                // nothing
                return awaiting_coroutine ? awaiting_coroutine : std::noop_coroutine();
            }
            void await_resume() noexcept {}
        };
        return transfer_awaitable{awaiting_coroutine};
    }

    // there are multiple ways to add co_await into coroutines
    // I used `await_transform`

    // use `co_await std::chrono::seconds{n}` to wait specified amount of time
    auto await_transform(std::chrono::seconds duration)
    {
        struct timer_awaitable
        {
            std::chrono::seconds duration;
            // always suspend
            bool await_ready()
            {
                return false;
            }

            // h is a handler for current coroutine which is suspended
            void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<task_promise_type> h)
            {
                // submit suspended coroutine to be resumed after timeout
                submit_timer_task(h, duration);
            }
            void await_resume() {}
        };

        return timer_awaitable{duration};
    }

    // also we can await other task<T>
    template<typename U>
    auto await_transform(task<U>& task)
    {
        if (!task.handle) {
            throw std::runtime_error("coroutine without promise awaited");
        }
        if (task.handle.promise().awaiting_coroutine) {
            throw std::runtime_error("coroutine already awaited");
        }

        struct task_awaitable
        {
            std::coroutine_handle<task_promise_type<U>> handle;

            // check if this task already has value computed
            bool await_ready()
            {
                return handle.promise().value.has_value();
            }

            // h - is a handle to coroutine that calls co_await
            // store coroutine handle to be resumed after computing task value
            void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h)
            {
                handle.promise().awaiting_coroutine = h;
            }

            // when ready return value to a consumer
            auto await_resume()
            {
                return std::move(*(handle.promise().value));
            }
        };

        return task_awaitable{task.handle};
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct task
{
    // declare promise type
    using promise_type = task_promise_type<T>;

    task(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> handle) : handle(handle) {}

    task(task&& other) : handle(std::exchange(other.handle, nullptr)) {}

    task& operator=(task&& other)
    {
        if (handle) {
            handle.destroy();
        }
        handle = std::exchange(other.handle, nullptr);
    }

    ~task()
    {
        if (handle) {
            handle.destroy();
        }
    }

    // interface for extracting value without awaiting on it

    bool is_ready() const
    {
        if (handle) {
            return handle.promise().value.has_value();
        }
        return false;
    }

    T get()
    {
        if (handle) {
            return std::move(*handle.promise().value);
        }
        throw std::runtime_error("get from task without promise");
    }

    std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> handle;
};

template<typename T>
task<T> task_promise_type<T>::get_return_object()
{
    return {std::coroutine_handle<task_promise_type>::from_promise(*this)};
}

// simple timers

// stored timer tasks
struct timer_task
{
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point target_time;
    std::coroutine_handle<> handle;
};

// comparator
struct timer_task_before_cmp
{
    bool operator()(const timer_task& left, const timer_task& right) const
    {
        return left.target_time > right.target_time;
    }
};

std::priority_queue<timer_task, std::vector<timer_task>, timer_task_before_cmp> timers;

void submit_timer_task(std::coroutine_handle<> handle, std::chrono::seconds timeout)
{
    timers.push(timer_task{std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + timeout, handle});
}

// timer loop
void loop()
{
    while (!timers.empty()) {
        auto& timer = timers.top();
        // if it is time to run a coroutine
        if (timer.target_time < std::chrono::steady_clock::now()) {
            auto handle = timer.handle;
            timers.pop();
            handle.resume();
        } else {
            std::this_thread::sleep_until(timer.target_time);
        }
    }
}

// example

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

task<int> wait_n(int n)
{
    std::cout << "before wait " << n << '\n';
    co_await std::chrono::seconds(n);
    std::cout << "after wait " << n << '\n';
    co_return n;
}

task<int> test()
{
    for (auto c : "hello world\n") {
        std::cout << c;
        co_await 1s;
    }

    std::cout << "test step 1\n";
    auto w3 = wait_n(3);
    std::cout << "test step 2\n";
    auto w2 = wait_n(2);
    std::cout << "test step 3\n";
    auto w1 = wait_n(1);
    std::cout << "test step 4\n";
    auto r = co_await w2 + co_await w3;
    std::cout << "awaiting already computed coroutine\n";
    co_return co_await w1 + r;
}

// main can't be a coroutine and usually need some sort of looper (io_service or timer loop in this example )
int main()
{
    // do something

    auto result = test();

    // execute deferred coroutines
    loop();

    std::cout << "result: " << result.get();
}
```

Output:

```
hello world
test step 1
before wait 3
test step 2
before wait 2
test step 3
before wait 1
test step 4
after wait 1
after wait 2
after wait 3
awaiting already computed coroutine
result: 6
```

Comment: Very nice answer. BTW, the line **handle = other.handle;** (inside your move-assignment) should rather be **handle = std::exchange(other.handle, {});**, right?

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get a ~13s hang at start, then after the "test step 4" line it segfaults (gcc 13, OSX).